# Why do I get an error 'Object is possibly 'undefined' when getting API data in typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I'm getting movie API data in react using typescript, it looks like this:

```
const [movies, setMovies] = useState<IMovie[]>();
 useEffect(() =>{
    fetchPopularMovies('popular').then((response) =>{
      setMovies(response.data.results);
    })
    console.log(movies);
  }, [])
```

API function:

```
export async function fetchPopularMovies(type:string) {
      let url: string = `${API_BASE}movie/${type}?api_key=${TMDB_API_KEY}`;
      const response = await axios.get<MovieResults>(url);
      return response;
}

const few_movies = movies ? movies.slice(1,7) : null;
```

It's a component which displays recent movies in a slider. I wanted to pass all movies through `App` component, but I need different movies in different components, so I decided to make different API calls in each component. But the problem is, when I try to write code like:  `{few_movies.map((movie, key)`, I get the next error: Object is possibly 'undefined'. And I think maybe the `useState` sets response data to movies too late, so it's not defined yet. And that's why my page doesn't display anything.
So my question is, how could I make sure the object is not undefined so it could display movies?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error `Object is possibly 'undefined'` comes from setting `few_movies` to `null` in the statement:

```
const few_movies = movies ? movies.slice(1,7) : null;
```

when the API call is happening.

I assume what you want to do is display your component with an empty list while the API call is being processed and then display the list of movies it fetches.

What you can do to achieve that is return an empty array `[]` instead of `null` when `movies` is being fetched.

So, change the initialisation of `few_movies` to:

```
const few_movies = movies ? movies.slice(1,7) : [];
```

and it should solve the issue.